# Concatenating mysql results into one field for each row result

Tags: mysql, symfony, csv

Having searched for an answer to my issue previously, I cannot really find a solution that best fits my problem.

I have a Symfony2 CRM which pulls in Jobs from a bespoke table in an OpenCart 1 database, but it also gathers data from other tables such as product, customer and attributes.

My issue is that because there are multiple attributes to a single product, I get repeated rows in the results and I need to export a CSV but gather the attributes within a single row.

Here's my current statement:

```
SELECT pd.name AS product_name, u.name AS staff_name, CONCAT(c.firstname, ' ', c.lastname) AS customer_name, 
s.stage AS stage_name, p.quantity, p.order_date, p.completion_date, p.PO_number, p.order_number, pa.text AS attribute_value, 
ad.name AS attribute_name 
FROM project p JOIN oc73_product_description pd ON pd.product_id = p.product_id 
JOIN user u ON u.id = p.staff_id JOIN stage s ON s.id = p.current_stage 
JOIN oc73_customer c ON c.customer_id = p.customer_id 
JOIN oc73_product_attribute pa ON pa.product_id = pd.product_id 
JOIN oc73_attribute_description ad ON ad.attribute_id = pa.attribute_id
```

This works fine, but for each separate attribute I get a new line, consequently repeated results. I tried to `GROUP_CONCAT` them but then I get only one result with ALL attributes in a single field when I really only want the attributes for the product within that result field.

Is there a means of amending this sql so I can achieve what I want? I really do not want to write two statements as this data will be used to export a CSV and I need all rows in one result set, if possible.

EDIT: Below is an example of how I'd like the attributes field to look.

> A: 2.00, B: 1.60, C: 1.72

Where A, B and C are the attribute names, and the numbers are the values.

I'd also be happy enough with two fields, like so:

> A,B,C | 2.00,1.60,1.72

So at least this way the data can be matched up. Ideally, though, I'd prefer the first method.

Comment: please provide an example how the desired result should look like

Answer (score -1):

Try without concatinuat first and last name, and use GROUP BY

Comment: This is not a solution, grouping will not put the attribute data into one field.